# Choose a path to folder using FileChooser in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to get the same effect as this tkinter code, but using Kivy.

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

root = Tk() 
root.withdraw() 

root.attributes('-topmost', True) 

open_file = filedialog.askdirectory() 
print(open_file)
```

I know that I can import it into Kivy and it works, but I wonder if there is any simple mechanism to do this in Kivy.

Comment: Have you read through the kivy documentation? There's mention of a [filechooser](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) widget.

Comment: I did and I tried applying file chooser - however it only allowed me to choose a file, which isn't a folder. I could take a path to .jpg for example, but not to a folder.

Comment: Red the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.dirselect). Try setting `dirselect` to `True`.